# Rails 3 Editing Join Table Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

In my app I have an `Athlete` which has many `sports`. I am trying to build out the edit account section where the user can edit the sports they play, but am stuck.

I have a Join table `UserSport` which has the fields of `athlete_id, sport_id, primary`. Here is my view:

```
      <% @athlete.user_sports.each do |user_sport| %>
        <% if user_sport.primary? %>
          <div class="row">
            <label>Primary Sport:</label>

            <%= f.semantic_fields_for :user_sports do |builder| %>
              <%= builder.select :sport_id, Sport.all.collect { |sp| [sp.name, sp.id] }, { include_blank: "Choose One", selected: user_sport.sport_id }, { class: "chosen field autosave primary-sport-select", :"data-form-selector" => "#athlete-form", id: "primary-sport-select" } %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        <% else %>
          <div class="row">
            <% if @athlete.user_sports.many? %>
            <label>More Sports</label>
            <% else %>

            <% end %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

I am not sure how to make it so that the user can change their primary sport

Answer (score 0):

1. list the @athlete rows into your table.
2. give each row an edit link that links to the `edit_athlete_path(@athlete)`
3. make your `Athlete` form include the field(s) for what sports they play
4. if you're writing any data into the `UserSport` table *from* the `Athlete` form, you'll need to give it permission to do so via the `attr_accessible` command in your models. and in that case, you'll want to go watch the railscast video about [nested models in forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: The adding of new sports works... its really editing the ones that are currently there, primarily editing an athlete's primary sport

Comment: so, in your controller for the edit form, for each sport they have listed, show a field. also, each one of those fields should have a radio button attached to the fiels(s) that says which one is primary.